# Questions not looping in Quiz App (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Rails and would appreciate if somebody could help me on this one. I am playing with this Quiz like application where I have a Question and Choice Controller and Model. And I have a Lessons Controller only with its respective view. My problem is for some reason regardless of how many questions I create, they are not looping, it keeps showing question with ID=1 all the time. I have been trying to figure this out for the past 2 days with no luck, any directions or hints, all welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
class LessonsController < ApplicationController

 def index
 end

 def start
 total = params[:number].to_i
 all = Question.where(:all).map {|x| x.id}
 session[:questions] = all.sort_by{rand}[0..(total-1)]

 session[:total]   = total
 session[:current] = 0
 session[:correct] = 0

 redirect_to :action => "question"
  end

 def question
 @current = session[:current]
 @total   = session[:total]

 if @current >= @total
    redirect_to :action => "end"
    return
  end 

  @question = Question.find_by(session[:questions][@current])
  @choices = @question.choices.sort_by{rand}

 session[:question] = @question
 session[:choices] = @choices

 end

 def answer

 @question = session[:questions]
 @current = session[:current]
 @total   = session[:total]

 @choiceid = params[:choice]

 @question = session[:question]
 @choices  = session[:choices]

 @choice = @choiceid ? Choice.find(@choiceid) : nil
 if @choice and @choice.correct
    @correct = true
    session[:correct] += 1
  else
    @correct = false
  end

  session[:current] += 1
end

 def end
 @correct = session[:correct]
 @total   = session[:total]

 @score = @correct * 100 / @total
 end



 end
```

index.html.erb

```
  <h1>Start Lesson</h1>

 <%= form_tag({:controller => "lessons",
              :action => "start"}) do %>
<p><%= label_tag(:number, "How many questions do you want in the
  lesson?", :id => "question") %></p>       
 <p class="center"><%= select_tag(:number, options_for_select((1..5).map 
 {|x| [x, x]}), :id => "count") %> <br /></p>

 <div class="center">
 <%= submit_tag "Start!", :class => "submit"%>
 </div>
 <% end %>

 <% content_for(:title) do %>
 Start Lesson!
 <% end %>
```

app/views/lessons/question.html.erb

```
<h1>Question <%= @current + 1 %> of <%= @total %></h1>
<p id="question"><%= @question.text %></p>

<%= form_tag({:controller => "lessons", :action => "answer"}) do %>
<% @choices.each do |choice| %>
 <p class="choice">
    <%= radio_button_tag(:choice, choice.id) %>
<%= label_tag("choice_".concat(choice.id.to_s).to_sym, choice.text) %>
 </p>
 <% end %>

 <div class="center">
 <%= submit_tag("Continue", :class => "submit") %>
 </div>
 <% end %>

 <% content_for(:title) do %>
 Question <%= @current + 1 %> of <%= @total %>
 <% end %>
```

answer.html.erb

```
 <h1>Question <%= @current + 1 %> of <%= @total %></h1>


 <div id="feedback-choices">
 <% @choices.each do |choice| %>
 <% if @choice.correct %>
    <p class="correct feedback-choice">
 <% elsif @choice == @choice %>
    <p class="incorrect feedback-choice">
 <% else %>
    <p class="feedback-choice">
 <% end %>
    <%= @choice.text %>
 </p>
 <% end %>
 </div>

 <p class="feedback">
 <% if @correct %>
 Correct!
 <% else %>
 Incorrect.
 <% end %>
</p>

<%= form_tag({:controller => "lessons", :action => "question"}) do %>
 <div class="center">
 <%= submit_tag("Continue", :class => "submit") %>
 </div>
 <% end %>

 <% content_for(:title) do %>
 Question <%= @current + 1 %> of <%= @total %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: There are so. many. things. wrong. with your code :/

For one: you have a method called `end`, `end` is a special ruby word, change the name of that method. 

Secondly, storing a whole question hash in session is not a good idea, do not rely on session to store complex data like that. 

Thirdly, maybe you should check what your `start` action is getting back as `params[:number]` since it might not be receiving that properly, so it sets your `total` to 0, causing your question to end after the first.

Comment: You shouldn't use end as method name, end is a keyword in ruby.